# Xamarin.Android Build Error for Xamarin Forms 4 Solution

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to compile a newly created Xamarin.Forms solution using Visual Studio Pro 2019 version 16.1.3. I use the stable Xamarin.Forms version 4.0.0.425677. The solution contains an iOS, Android and UWP project.

When I try to compile I get the following Android compilation error even without having made any code changes.

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3326,2): error : A part of the path "AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.class" could not be found**

The only related post I found was [here](https://github.com/AndyCW/MovesenseDotNet/issues/8) which recommends to delete bin and obj folders in the Android project. This does not apply since I start with an new solution in the first place. Any ideas what the cause could be?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that I only get this issue when I have the term "Xamarin" in my Android project name. This seems to confuse the Android compiler.

Comment: Well if the issue is having Xamarin, and you rename after creating the solution, so it most likely will preserve the issue. Why not just remove Xamarin from the project name?

Comment: I would like the namespace and the respective project name to be the same for ease of finding your way around in the solution if you are new to the development team. And if you have several technologies "living" in the same namespace I will need Xamarin in the namespace ( and therefore also in project name ).